# Flutter firestore how get document one by one?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

There are documents in the collection in Firestore. I list these documents on the screen according to the user's email address. But I want to import each document separately. Each document has an array called title. When I want to get the array of each document separately, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: type '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

CODE:

```dart
Widget getCustomerRepairLog() {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!; //better do a null check 1st
  late final _repairLogs = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Repair').get();
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: _repairLogs,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<Widget> items = [];
        final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
        if (data == null) return Text("got null");

        for (final eleman in data) {
          if (eleman.data()['email']! == user.email) {
            for (final item in eleman.data()['title']) {
              items.add(Text("${item}"));
            }
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [Text(eleman)],
            );
          }
        }
        // return Row(children: [Icon(Icons.done_all_rounded), ...items]);
        // return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,children: [...items]);
        // return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code solution:

```
Widget getCustomerRepairLog() {
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!; //better do a null check 1st
late final _repairLogs =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Repair').get();
return FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: _repairLogs,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<Widget> items = [];
      final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
      if (data == null) return Text("got null");

      for (final eleman in data) {
        final currentData = eleman.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        if (currentData  ['email']! == user.email) {
          for (final item in currentData['title']) {
            items.add(Text("${item}"));
            
          }
          return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,children: 
   [Text(currentData.toString())]); // this represents Map<String, dynamic> 
        }
      }
      // return Row(children: [Icon(Icons.done_all_rounded), ...items]);
      // return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,children: [...items]);
      
      // return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  });
  }
```

here I change `elemant` in the `Text` widget which is a whole `DocumentSnaphot` with its data which is `Map<String, dynamic>` :

```
  Text(element); // this represents DocumentSnapshot which is not a String so it throws the error

  Text(currentData.toString()); // this represents the document's Map<String, dynamic> data which I make it a String with the toString()
```

Comment: current is not defined anywhere. Does it have to be currentData?

Comment: yes, sorry my mistake, I will change it

Comment: try the code now

Comment: yes, its worked. But Instead of getting all the data, there is an array called title in it. just how can i get them?

Comment: ues I give you how to show all data, you can access it like you will do in a Map, like this Text(currentData['title'].toString())

Comment: Thank you, When I did toString(), I needed to get it as a string, not as an array, but when I tried, I failed. Finally, I would like to ask this. Can I print the title array in other documents in the same function like this? A Card design I want to do. Card will write the titles of each document one after the other. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (data[index].data()['email'] == user.email) {
      final item = data[index].data()['title'];
      return Text("${item}");
    }
    return Container();
  },
),
```